# Approximating an integral with another integral with finite limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, improper-integrals

I came across the following integral in my work

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{(1- \  \ 2 \pi j s  \theta)^{m}}-1}{2\pi j s }\ e^{-2\pi j s\sigma^2}\ ds $$

Assuming $\theta,m,\sigma^2$ are non-negative but nocessarly integers, and $j$ is the imaginary unit.

I tried solving numerically (MATLAB) by replacing the infinite limits by the following $$\int_{-L}^{L} \frac{\frac{1}{(1-\  \ 2 \pi j s  \theta)^{m}}-1}{2\pi j s }\ e^{-2\pi j s\sigma^2}\ ds $$

It seems to me there is a singularity point at $s=0$ but the integral still exists even if there is singularity point.

Some tricks have to be done in MATLAB and what I did is, split the integral into two parts at the singularity point and taking the limit over that space to be almost zero.

My question is what would be the best choice of the finite limit $L$? in other words how can one approximate the error from using the approximation? I would like to have the best limits and not have $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ because that would take a whole lot of time.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Are you really sure the integration range is $(-\infty,+\infty)$? The integrand function has a singularity in $s=-1/\theta$. Moreover, what do you mean by "the best choice of $L$"? The best choice under which constraints?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio please check the new integral, I am actually quite sure about this one. What I mean by best choice of $L$ is that for example an integration outside $L$ is approximately zero..

Comment: $e^{-2\pi js\sigma^2}$ does not decay, assuming that $j$ is the imaginary unit. It is a sinusoid. This integral is approached via principal values, most likely. Look into the Hilbert transform.

Comment: @Henry: $s=\frac{1}{2\pi j \theta}$ is still a non-integrable singularity in the general case.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio s is a real number, what do you exactly mean?

Comment: @Henry: are you able to compute the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{(s-1)^4}$? I bet not, since $s=1$ is a non-integrable singularity of the integrand function ($\frac{1}{(s-1)^4}$, in this case).

Comment: I voted for closing since it makes no sense to me to looking for approximation of non-converging integrals.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio actually I can give u the published paper that has such an integral I think its fair enough before you vote for closing.. right?

Comment: @Henry: that is not the point. Probably in your paper they deal with non-converging integral by considering principal values or something similar. However, without being specific, this question is simply nonsensical.

Comment: then maybe you can explain to me how one can approach this problem using principal values, as I said in my question I know that there is singularity points, I don't understand how they can overcome it.. @Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: @CameronWilliams thanks can you give more advice, why do you think we can only approach via principal values

Comment: Principal values are likely the only way to make sense of this integral.

Comment: In your opinion, if I choose to compute numerically, let us say with the help of MATLAB, should one account for such singularities or should MATLAB be able to compute ? @CameronWilliams

Comment: You probably want to use the FFT to compute the Hilbert transform.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio just FYI http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularIntegral.html

Comment: For some suitable sense of that expression (the principle value), I think the OPs question would be answered by an asymptotic error estimate between the original principle value and the definite integral over $(-L,L)$. I'd expect the error to be an asymptotic series in $L$, that also depends on the other parameters ($\theta$,$m$, and $\sigma$). Then for a level of acceptable error, the OP can choose $L$ that achieves this.

Comment: Thanks @rajb245, I was actually looking to see if my way of analyzing such a problem is correct...

Comment: Beware - attempting to use naive quadrature techniques on Cauchy principal value integrals will give you nonsensical results.

Comment: This kind of improprer integral with singularity is commonly encountered in some Fourier transforms. The results are piecewise functions. One of the simplest example is the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{x}$ which result is : $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i\pi xy}}{x}dx = i\sqrt{2\pi}\big(H(y)-\frac{1}{2}\big)$ where $H(y)$ is the Heaviside's step function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the joint page, it is shown that the result, in case $m>0$ and $\frac{\sigma^2}{\theta}>0$ , is:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{(1- \  \ 2 \pi j s  \theta)^{m}}-1}{2\pi j s }\ e^{-2\pi j s\sigma^2}\ ds = \frac{\Gamma(m\:,\:\frac{\sigma^2}{\theta})}{\Gamma(m)}$$
The method consists in the change of variables leading to two known Fourier transforms.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, I want to ask yo is there any restrictions on $m$, should it be a positive integer only for example...@JJacquelin

Comment: Purely from theoretical consideration (not tested with numerical means) I think that the formula is OK for real $m>0$. Certainly not for $m\leq 0$.

Comment: I just carried out several tests with non-integer $m>0$. The results are in good agreement. ( the tests with integer $m>0$ have been done before).

Comment: Than k you very much, i tried too and the results is correct. I will give the bounty to you. you have helped alot.

Comment: it seems the bounty has expired before you have answered the question...

Comment: Doesn't matter, I don't care for bounty. You are welcome.